# Spring boot Full Calendar, unable to return json

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I need help with this, seems to parsing issue with the json object. I believe it needs an json array instead of just json element? Please help. thanks in advance.

here is my calendar.html

```
<script>
$.getJSON(window.location.href + '/getRoster', function(data) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header : {
                left : 'prev,next today',
                center : 'title',
                right : 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate : '2017-09-12',
            navLinks : true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable : false,
            eventLimit : false, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events : [ data ]
        });

    }); });
   </script>
```

Heres my controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/calendar/getRoster", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getRoster(HttpServletResponse response) {

    List<Duty> dutyList = dutyService.findAll();
    log.info("Size: {}", dutyList.size());
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        String role = dutyList.get(i).getDuty();
        String name = dutyList.get(i).getName();
        String title = role + ": " + name;
        String startDate = sdf.format(dutyList.get(i).getStartDutyDate());
        String endDate = sdf.format(dutyList.get(i).getEndDutyDate());

        log.info("Title: {} startDate: {} endDate: {}", title, startDate, endDate);

        map.put("title", title);
        map.put("start", startDate);
        map.put("end", endDate);

    }

    String json = new Gson().toJson(map);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as follows, Spring will automatically transform the map into json string for response and you don't need to set `HttpServletResponse` as input variable.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calendar/getRoster", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json; charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody String getRoster() {
    ...
    ...
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But it only returns the contents for the last loop. How do I return everything in the dutyList?

Comment: Because the keys you use in map are identical, it will definitely return the result of last loop. You should create a data object as a class to store each item in dutyList and push the instance into map, then return the map.